# Formatting columns with multiple types

Tags: c#, winforms

I have currency text and numeric type values in my datagridview columns. I would like to format the currency value using the below code, but it's not working.

```
private void gv_EmployeeAdditional_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (gv_EmployeeAdditional.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmpDatatype"].Value.ToString() == "Currency")
    {
        gv_EmployeeAdditional[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex-1].Style.Format = "#,##0.00##";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your code?

Comment: need to format the particular cell having the type currency using this code not getting any error not getting output

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it right now but I think this is what you are looking for, set a break-point and make sure you are getting inside of the if statement then run a few test cases...

```
    if (gv_EmployeeAdditional.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmpDatatype"].Value.ToString() == "Currency")
    {
        gv_EmployeeAdditional.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
        gv_EmployeeAdditional.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        //gv_EmployeeAdditional[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex - 1].Style.Format = "#,##0.00##";
    }
```

Maybe even just try set this line:

```
gv_EmployeeAdditional[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex - 1].Style.Format = "N2";
```

Formatting types in C# [link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thank you
changed default cell style to cell then its worked for single cell other wise its applicable to whole column
gv_EmployeeAdditional.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Value"].Style.Format="N2";
                gv_EmployeeAdditional.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Value"].ValueType = typeof(decimal);

Comment: @Venket, glad i could help you get there, haven't worked on Winforms in ages but recalled a similar problem a while back.